# Is it possible to find middle element of a linked list by single pass and single pointer?

Tags: singly-linked-list

I was asked in interview, i had given multiple solutions by 2 pointers, hashtable and bruteforce method. But again interviewer asked me to do by single pass and single pointer. I said its impossible!. Let me know if anybody have any idea on this.